# O que significa essa expressão?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mustache.js

Estudando um pouco o Node-Red me deparei com a seguinte expressão, `{{#header.url}`.

Várias expressões do tipo estão presentes no código, por exemplo: `{{/header.url}}`, `{{#header.image}}`, etc. Segue um trecho de código:

```
<span class="logo">{{#header.url}}<a href="{{.}}">{{/header.url}}{{#header.image}}<img src="{{.}}" title="{{version}}">{{/header.image}} <span>{{ header.title }}</span>{{#header.url}}</a>{{/header.url}}</span>
<ul class="header-toolbar hide">
```

Alguém saberia me dizer o que essa expressão está fazendo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso é muito típico de [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/), uma linguagem de templates que compila pata HTML.

A versão JavaScript ([Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)) tem um exemplo na documentação:

View:

```
{
  "person": false
}
```

Template:

```
Shown.
{{#person}}
Never shown!
{{/person}}
```

Output:

```
Shown.
```

Ou seja, configura-se um objeto com propriedades, depois no template o que estiver entre `{{#person}}` e `{{/person}}` será incluído se `pessoa` for `true`.

Comment: Então, por exemplo, ao invés de eu escrever todo html pra carregar imagens, links e etc, eu posso configurar o mustache de modo que ele gere isso tudo pra mim?

Comment: @FernandoMessiasdaSilva em particular o mustache é muito fanático em relação a lógica. Eles "proibem" lógica no template. Se conseguires ter a lógica no JS e fazer o template mostrar o que queres ótimo. Senão há muitas outras linguagens que fazem isso. Acho que a minha resposta vai de encontro à tua pergunta. Se tiveres outra pergunta específica sobre uma situação onde queres escrever html com lógica para imagens e links: sugiro colocares outra pergunta.